# Django application for viewing web reports

Tags: python, django, csv, django-models, report

I want to create a web application using django. I have a .csv file that is generated every week from the central database, and I need to use it to build a web reporting tool.

I'm wondering how to create the small web interface that will let me to apply the filters and display the results of pivoting the data from this file.

What is the best architecture for this dev? Import each time the file to my model or to display results directly? Are there some libraries for this?

Comment: Could you give a use case for your imagined web reporting tool?

Comment: A csv file is, in a sense, a type of database. Unfortunately, it's not a very good one for what you are proposing because (a.) file i/o is notoriously slow, and (b.) it has exactly zero features that make an RDBMS useful. Why not build the web report on top of the very database that generated the CSV in the first place?

Comment: I don't have the acess to the tool generating this file. For use cases - there are some data that should be tracked in sliding period of time and the columns that should be used to create the pivot tables The users should be able to select the filters like : area, website type, call numbers. And see the table generated and a small chart.